# Alternative to This in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, this, selectors-api

I have this code on codepen: https://codepen.io/RaoniSousa/pen/Zpkxbb:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.label'), //label com ID label,
    z = document.querySelectorAll('.input'); //input com ID name;

function myFunction() {
'use strict';
if (this.value !== "" ) {
    this.style.opacity = '1';
    this.style.bottom = '4em';
    this.style.color = '#722872';
    console.log(this);
} else {
    this.style.opacity = '0';
    this.style.bottom = '1.5em';
    console.log(this);
    }
}
```

In the function above i'd like to change only the style of the label (var x). I know the '***this***' is referring to .input (var z), but, i'd like to apply a style to label as i change his related input value, but if i use a for loop, he calls all label one the same time. Is there a way to call var x intead of var z by using '***this.style***' or somebody knows another alternative to this code?

I'd like it works as happens here(roll down the bar till reach *Contact Me* section): https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/YqLyXB

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function myFunction() {
    'use strict';
    if (this.value !== "" ) {
        this.nextElementSibling.style.opacity = '1';
        this.nextElementSibling.style.bottom = '2em';
        this.nextElementSibling.style.color = '#722872';
        console.log(this.nextElementSibling);
    } else {
        this.style.opacity = '.4';
        this.style.bottom = '.5em';
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```